# Не определяется endl

Tags: c++, qt

Учусь работать в qt, загрузил пример с интернета
Вот код:

```
#include <QTextStream> // подключаем необходимый заголовочный файл


int main() {

    QTextStream out(stdout);

    // Создаем строку типа QString
    QString a = "love";

    // Добавляем текст в конец строки
    a.append(" chess");

    // Добавляем текст в начало строки
    a.prepend("I ");

    // Выводим строку
    out << a << endl;

    // Выводим количество символов строки
    out << "The a string has " << a.count() << " characters" << endl;

    // Выводим всю строку в верхнем регистре
    out << a.toUpper() << endl;

    // Выводим всю строку в нижнем регистре
    out << a.toLower() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

На каждую строчку с endl выдает ошибку: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'

Comment: А это все от того, что вы всегда пишите `using namesppace std;`... А вообще не понятно, зачем? просто добавить `\n` в конец строки нельзя?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#endl

Comment: @こきん спасибо за отличное решение, которое выдает ряд новых ошибок. Все способы по использованию переноса строк я пробовал (да про iostream я тоже знаю), ничего не помогло кроме итогового решения. Мой скудный опыт не позволил понять в чем проблема, но qt отказывается принимать все способы (без <QTextStream> все работает это так к слову)

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Если кто-то столкнется с данной проблемой то для них напишу здесь решение, потому что нигде я этой информации не нашел. Чтобы не было данной ошибки нужно писать вот так...

```
out << "Qt rocks!" << Qt::endl;
```